# Ragel Java outputs [nulla,b] instead of [a,b,c]

Tags: java, ragel

I would like to code a CSVReader State Machine in ragel, since I've doned mine in Java with Enums already. The returned list should be [a,b,c] but I get [nulla,b]. I'm using Ragel 6.8 on Fedora 22, I really hope any one could help me

This is the source:

```
%%{

machine csv_reader_java;
seperator = (';'|',');
letter = [A-Za-z0-9]*;

main := |*
seperator => { putToList(tokens, string); };
letter => { emit(data, tokens, ts, te); };
space;
*|;

}%%

import java.util.*;

public class CSVReader {

private String string;

public void emit(char[] data, List<String> tokens, int ts, int te) {
     char output = data[ts];
     string += output;
}
public void putToList(List<String> tokens, String data){
tokens.add(data);
string = "";
}

%% write data;

public List<String> split(char[] data) {
    int cs; /* state number */
    int p = 0, /* start of input */
    pe = data.length, /* end of input */
    eof = pe,
    ts, /* token start */
    te, /* token end */
    act /* used for scanner backtracking */;

    List<String> tokens = new ArrayList<String>();

    %% write init;
    %% write exec;

    return tokens;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(new CSVReader().split("a,b,c".toCharArray()));
}
}
```

And this is what it returns me:
`[nulla, b]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking over this, I see two problems. The first is the null at the start of your output, which I think is caused by not initializing `string` when parsing starts, which leaves it `null`. When the `emit` call reaches `string += output;`, `string` is `null`, so it appends the current token ("a") to the string representation of `null`, resulting in "nulla". Initializing `string` with `""` would fix this.

The second problem, the one of not adding "c" to the list, is even simpler. The tokens only get added to the list when a separator is found, and since there is no separator after "c", that token doesn't get added. You could solve this by calling an action on end-of-file to `emit` the current token string if it isn't empty.

Comment: nice, that is pretty much all I need :-)